# Grails, ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: grails

I have the following exception **with grails 2.5.5** :

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:394)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$ValueIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:409)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at org.grails.jaxrs.web.JaxrsFilter.doFilterInternal(JaxrsFilter.java:46)
    at com.cbp.clavis.filtre.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

With this stacktrace it is not possible to understand why I have this exception, there is no direct link between PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter and LinkedHashMap$ValueIterator.next.

The context : I launch some ajax requests to the same controller action, which has no state of course :

```
def myMethode(MyCommand criteria){
    def count = myService.countByCriteria(criteria)
    def result = [statut: "ok", total: count]
    render result as JSON
}
```

Any idea ?

Thks

Comment: What version of Grails?

Comment: thks, question edited

Comment: I think I'm seeing something very similar (also in grails 2.5.5) although my stacktrace includes a line in one of my controllers.